# Is it ok to refuse housekeeping services at a hotel?

Tags: hotels, services

I'm about to stay at a 4-star hotel in Stockholm for 5 days. Is it ok to request that I *don't* want my room to be cleaned or the housekeeping staff to enter the room?

The reason for this is mainly that I'm traveling with my dog (yes, the hotel is aware of this) and although he will be in a travel cage while I'm away, it would be best if there were as little distractions as possible. The other reason is that I'm generally not keen on having strangers in a room with my personal stuff and I don't really need a new towel every day.

Can I just tell the staff at checkin that I don't want housekeeping or should I contact them beforehand? Are hotels generally ok with it or do they want to check that everything's ok with the room during the stay?

Comment: Not exactly an answer to the question, so putting as a comment. A **** hotel should be pretty open to (almost) all requests from guests. So your best bet is just to ask (either now, or when you arrive.) They may say yes, they may say no, they may say yes and ignore you anyway. But there shouldn't be any issue with you asking.

Comment: I'm reminded of [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sMI3m7IDkxI) scene from the 1973 movie **Paper Chase**.

Comment: Yes it's okay.  But whatever you do, don't refuse the [little bars of soap](http://www.columbia.edu/~sss31/rainbow/soap.story.html)

Comment: If it's a Starwood hotel, [they'll even give you points or F&B credit if you decline housekeeping on some days](http://www.starwoodhotels.com/corporate/about/citizenship/sustainability/programs.html?language=en_US)

Comment: Well I assume that's why most hotels (probably all I visited so far) have a "Don't disturb" card... There is no reason why it should bother them, it's less work. But I hope you don't leave your dog in a cage for too long ;(

Comment: @VerenaHaunschmid Thanks for the concern! The conference venue I'm attending is next door so he won't be alone for more than 3-4 hours at a stretch :)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I think it is perfectly okay to reject housekeeping services at a hotel. I do this all the time. On arrival I set it up that the room is only serviced "on request" that way my things and other stuff doesn't get disturbed. And most hotels are generally very happy to comply and appreciate it.

Comment: in fact I've stayed at places that offered to donate $10 a day to charity if I would say I didn't need housekeeping. Done!

Comment: The one I've used a lot recently gives bonus points every 3 days to people who do this because it's "good for the environment" which I'm sure is more just "good for their wallet".

Comment: Once you've done this, make sure to leave a Do Not Disturb card out, too. Hotels aren't renowned for excellent internal communications.

Comment: The Story Hotel in Stockholm puts up a sign in their bathroom that they save money if you reuse your towels and it's also good for the environment...

Comment: Definitely accepted and encouraged by hotels these days. I would see if I could catch the housekeeping staff as well and just tell them why. Usually they are very happy to help and will not want to upset your dog.

Answer (score 26):

Yes, just hang the "DO NOT DISTURB" sign on the outside of the door. That's what it's for. You can tell the front desk as well in case it falls off. The comments below emphasise it is important to tell the front desk if you are staying for several days.

If you need any fresh towels or toiletries, or you want the bedding changed or anything like this, you can phone the front desk to arrange for it to be done at your convenience. (Perhaps when taking the dog for a walk.)

Comment: I wouldn't exactly rely on the DND sign, since, even if it doesn't fall off, it's trivial for a bored teen to flip it as a prank.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs At a four star hotel in Stockholm? I think it is more likely the front desk/cleaning staff will forget to honour a verbal request, to be honest.

Comment: I assure you that having four stars as a hotel does NOT prevent any of your guests pulling pranks on one another. Or do **** hotels have a magical field that prevents such things? All it takes is one bored adolescent with a naughty streak to take a 2 second action. It's certainly a good advice to hang the sign, but it's not foolproof. As you say, also inform the front desk.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs Usually the price is a magical field. I mean, I cannot guarantee it, but I don't think I've even seen a teenager in a hotel this year.

Comment: I have seen my fair share of obnoxious children/teens in 4/5* hotels, so (for example) those who were on holiday with their parents would be likely offenders.

Comment: Some hotels/countries have requirements to check on the guest every X days, DND or not. I've had a slightly worried visit from the manager on duty + security guard + housekeeping one time when I'd left the DND sign on the door for a long time!

Comment: Most hotels I've been to seem to only respecct the DND sign for so long. I wouldn't rely on it.

Comment: Agreed. If this is all you do, it likely won't work for 4 days; I've had letters under the door, and calls from the front desk, when doing this in the past (mostly security worries, not cleanliness). Put the sign on the door as a reminder, but ask at the front desk when you check in too.

Answer (score 10):

5 Days is at the limit for most hotels other than long-stay hotels - they will want to check that their room is still ok. You can ask them - they might be ok with it. And you can certainly get 3 days without room service at most hotels. Just be aware that past 3 days, they will probably want to enter your room even if you have your DND sign, and they may require it as one of the listed conditions..

Comment: I think it's worth noting that just because they may have a requirement to check on the room every X days, it doesn't mean they have to do it *when you're not there*. You should be able to set up a time with the staff that fits with your schedule and you can arrange to be there (with the dog and your personal belongings) while they do their thing.